# Beamer: What's the best way to put 8 figures on one slide?

Tags: beamer

I want to put 8 figures on one slide so it is laid out like:

```
X X X X
X X X X
```

I thought about creating 4 columns with 2 figures each, but figured there was a better way of doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: If they are the same size, the simplest option may be a `tabular`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, you don't need captions for each individual figure and all figures are equally large:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image}\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

With a numbered subcaption for each individual image (For unnumbered captions, add `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` to the preamble.):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image}}\bigskip

\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption text]{\includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{shared caption for all images}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I need captions?

Comment: That depends on how exactly your captions should look like. Do you want numbered captions? If so, does each image get its own figure number or do you want subcaptions? Please also clarify the expected alignment of the captions with respect to the images.

Comment: I want a caption for each figure, and each underneath each figure.

Comment: @Woj: Do you want numbered or unnumbered captions? Do you also need the "figure" prefix? Do you want your captions to be horizontally centered, justified...? Please be a bit more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Unnumbered, no figure number, no figure prefix, centered

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the *best* way, but here's *a* way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 1
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 2
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 3
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 4
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 5
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 6
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 7
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
Figure 8
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```